# LinearLayout: how to place a view below/right of a fill_parent view?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to have a TextView on the left that fills space, plus a right-justified TextView on the right. I've tried fiddling with gravity, layout_gravity, and making the second TextView fill_parent also, but the second TextView always ends up invisible as long as the first one is fill_parent. I notice that the same problem occurs if the LinearLayout is vertical. What to do?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left Side"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right side"
        android:background="#ff606060"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Target: Android 2.2

Comment: This is because the fill_parent is pushing your rightmost textview off screen.  Weights are the way to do this.  I have had to do this myself.  Seems to me that Google would implement a fills_void capability so that if you had one view that you wanted to be static, and another that you wanted to fill the rest, that it would do just that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want.
You can also add singleLine (and ellipsize) to the left view if you don't want it to wrap text.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left Side"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right side"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:singleLine="true"` seems sufficient; the text is ellipsized by default.

Comment: You're right, I've been adding some excess attributes lately, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

use `layout_weight` and set `layout_width` to `0dp` on both your `TextView`.
So weight set to 3 on the first TextView, then 1 on the second for example/

Comment: Thanks. Actually `layout_width="0"` has an undesired effect (the TextViews are not sized according to their content) so I just set `layout_width="wrap_content"` on both views and then `layout_weight="1" `(or any positive number) on the left view to cause it to fill space. The `gravity` attribute doesn't seem to do anything so I have removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a RelativeLayout?

Set the right-justified TextView to layout_alignParentRight, then set the other one that fills the space to layout_alignParentLeft and layout_toLeftOf the right-justified TextView